# Current president of 10 years ago

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence below, I want to say that the president of e.g. 10 years ago did something; can I use "*current*" here? If not, what word suits here?

> The *current* president ordered all of the military units to be ready around the borders.

Somehow, a similar [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202697/past-tense-equivalent-of-the-word-current) has been asked earlier, but this isn't quite same so I still haven't got my answer.

Consider this is a documentary and the speaker wants to say that someone (who we don't know who is that) has given an order to the military, the speaker says, (e.g.) John Smith, the (current president of that time) ordered this, the point is that, that guy isn't the president anymore, so we can't use "sitting president", since sitting means the one who is still the president, and in the given context we don't know who is John Smith, so we need that the speaker points out that Smith is the president of that time, I just found it odd to use "current" here, so I'm asking what should be used here, since I have searched on different dictionaries and example sources and didn't find that "current" be used in such examples, so which word should I use?

Comment: The ***current*** president can only ever be used to refer to someone who ***is*** president at time of speaking / writing. It's irrelevant how long ago he/she ***became*** president.

Comment: Presumably in your context the subject ***is*** currently president, otherwise he couldn't order the military about. Why should anyone care whether he was president 10 years ago (and may or may not have held that office continuously since then)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [past-tense equivalent of the word "current"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202697/past-tense-equivalent-of-the-word-current)

Comment: You can say e.g. 'In 1949, the then current president, Harry S Truman...' or leave out 'then current' altogether.

Comment: I was about to answer with "[**sitting**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sitting) president", but a duplicate has been found.

Comment: The then-president

Comment: I deleted an answer I was working on because it got too complicated, but besides these suggestions: *if the context establishes the time frame well enough*, you should be able to simply use "the president" and it will be understood as "the president at the time." E.g. "England's Royal Navy expanded greatly in the late 1500s, as the queen ordered construction of new ships." "The queen" is understood as the queen of England in the late 1500s, not Queen Elizabeth II.

Comment: "The president at the time".....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say

> The then president ordered ...

or

> Then president John Smith ordered ...

or

> The  president then, John Smith,  ordered ...